# Tns build error: sed: no such file or directory

Tags: nativescript

Month ago I've successfully completed ns tutorial without using angular2. Today I wanted to compete tutorial with NS+angular2. I've installed ng-groceries, but it didn't go well when i did tns run android(iOS). Then I decided to try to check if i can complete just NS groceries tutorial and got the same problem. I have it even with Hello World template. I get the following errors when i do tns run.

For android :

1)

> No manifest found in /Users/avmax/sandbox/web/study/tutorials/native-script/HelloWorld/app/App_Resources/Android/AndroidManifest.xml

2)

> Execution failed for task ':processF0DebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute apt

3)

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/avmax/sandbox/web/study/tutorials/native-script/HelloWorld/app/App_Resources'

For iOS :

1)

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/avmax/sandbox/web/study/tutorials/native-script/HelloWorld/platforms/ios/HelloWorld/Resources'

2)

> We have failed to check if we need to add a compatability LaunchScreen.xib due to: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/avmax/sandbox/web/study/tutorials/native-script/HelloWorld/app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist'

tns doctor :

> Your components are up-to-date.
>   No issues were detected.

I have :

> tns --version :  2.5.3
>
> nodejs -v : 7.7.3

How can i fix these errors?

Comment: You could try to install the latest LTS node version `6.10.3` -https://nodejs.org/en/ and to upgrade to latest NartiveScript 3.0 `npm install nativescript --g`. then you could verify whether you will have the same problem, while using clear project `tns create sample --ng` and to build it `tns run <platform name>`

Comment: @NikolayTsonev thanks! I got the solution - had to clean my nam cache and install tns version >= 3.0

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to have tns version >= 3.0 installed. And also it would be useful to clean npm cache in case of desire to install native-script tutorials